# window.location is not working inside the js function

Tags: javascript, php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
//if i put window.location= "index.php" here not inside js function it worked but I need it to be inside a function
function newLoad() {
    window.location= "index.php"
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" value="press here" onclick="newLoad()">

</body>
</html>
```

any Ideas how can I make it work inside the javascript function ?

Comment: Define _not working_!!

Comment: does not direct to index.php

Comment: Your code should run, so what is different?

Comment: your code is working.

Comment: Have you work via any PHP framework

Comment: Works for me no problem.  I put your index.php and file with Javascript function in the same directory.

Comment: yea thank u all it worked... i had a weird error

Answer (score 0):

Your code works. Howether, you don't need to use javascript.

```
<a href="index.php">
   <button>press here</button>
</a>
```